# VS2010 not opening files when opening a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I open my project in VS2010 it doesn't re-open the files that I had open last time I closed the solution (and I would like it to).

The worked until last week, now it doesn't work for any of my solutions.

I've read elsewhere that this information is kept in the SUO file.  I've checked, and the SUO file is there.  If I delete the SUO file it is re-created, but that doesn't fix the problem.  The selected startup project is also kept in the SUO file, and that is being remembered correctly when the solution is re-opened.

I can't find an option that controls this behavior.

Any ideas for what to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to `Tools>Import and Export Settings` In Visual Studio and resetting your settings in Visual Studio. There is a reset all settings option in it.
I have seen people say that has worked for them.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I tried to compare the before-and-after settings files to try and figure out which setting made the difference, but there were too many differences...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the windows layout setting. If you go to import/export and export all but the windows layout under the general tag then import it all you will be fine or you can export them all and just uncheck the windows layout when importing.

I have been having this problem for a long time finally just decided to import and export with certain check boxes checked and ones not checked until I found the culprit.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some formatting to make your answer easier to read? Thanks!